# Python Path whic is later in sys.path list getting picked ahead

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Aren't modules searched for in the order of the paths in sys.path?

I printed sys.path at the point in the code where an import is failing.
The sys.path entries are in the below order.

```
['/home/xyz/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib',
...
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

The import statement is `"from google.api.control import client as control_client"`. 
The right path where 'google.api.control' module is present is `'/home/xyz/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib'`. 
However, I printed `google.api.__path__` just before the import statement, and the path is `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api'`

Why is the path ahead in the list not getting picked?

Comment: Maybe it didn't find it at the first path. Are you sure it was present there?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my import paths when I introduced endpoints into my project. In my case, google.__path__ wouldn't recognize files from the app engine SDK. I "solved" it by adding "import google.api" before my troublesome import. This caused python to change the google.__path__ and everything worked. The endpoints and app engine SDK must have some naming collisions that need resolving. Ugly. But it worked.

Comment: Illusionist: Yes, I printed the paths.

@HondaGuy: I did add "import google.api" before the troubling "from google.api.control import client as control_client". I still see the issue.
Any idea why google.api in site-packages doesn't include the control.client?
I even tried "pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client". But don't see control.client in site-packages.

Comment: control.client is part of endpoints-management-python. This should come down if you pip install google-endpoints. The docs suggest using the following:
"pip install google-endpoints --extra-index-url=https://gapi-pypi.appspot.com/admin/nurpc-dev"

Comment: @HondaGuy That was helpful. I forgot the installation of endpoints to standard python path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @HondaGuy, installing 'google-endpoints' to standard python packages path is one way to deal with the issue.

```
pip install google-endpoints
```